# Function reuse with the declared variable list name automatically updating

Tags: python

I have a function that can load every data in the image folder and save them to a list. I want to reuse this function to load another dataset but should be stored in a different variable name

"""
The next step is to write a function that can load every data in the image folder and save them to a list
"""

```
def load_images(path):
    global Full_image_data 
    Full_image_data = []
    for i in glob.glob(path):
        images=Image.open(i)
        Full_image_data.append(images)
    return Full_image_data
```

"""
The next step is to write a function that can resize the images and save them to a list
"""

```
def resize_images():
    Resized_images=[]
    for re in range(len(Full_image_data)):
        a=Full_image_data[re].resize((256,256))
        Resized_images.append(a)
    return Resized_images
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Your function doesn't really do anything useful, because it terminates without returning anything (and returns `None`). So the list you create is immediately garbage collected when the function terminates. Probably, you want to `return Full_image_data` at the end, then the *caller* is responsible for assigning the output to whatever it wants: `foo = load_images(path1); bar = load_images(path2)`

Comment: Then take the list you want to update as an argument, or have each call to `load_images` return the list for the caller to manage as desired.

Comment: Note that you're not saving the image data in the list, you're just saving the file objects. You need to call `read()` to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a "return" statement.  Your function appends a bunch of images to a list but then doesn't do anything with the list.  If you return that list to the calling context, then you can name the results anything you like for subsequent calls to different paths.

```
def load_images(path):
    Full_image_data =[]
    for i in glob.glob(path):
        images=Image.open(i)
        Full_image_data.append(images)
    return Full_image_data

images1 = load_images('/path/to/images')
images2 = load_images('/path/to/more/images')
```

ETA:

Do NOT use a global variable if you want to load different paths to different lists.

In order for your other function to do something with different lists of images, you will need to pass each list in as a function parameter, something like this:

```
def resize_images(image_list):
    Resized_images=[]
    for image in image_list:
        Resized_images.append(image.resize((256,256))
    return Resized_images

resized_images = resize_images(load_images('/path/to/images'))
```

Note the comment on your original post about reading the file data.  I am not familiar with the image processing specifically, so you'll want to doublecheck that.

Comment: Thanks. I was about to update my question. don't know if you can still help out

Comment: it is the same images. I want to resize the image I loaded with the first function